# Apple Production Push Services Notification Issues

Tags: php, linux, apple-push-notifications

i hope someone able to help me out on this case

i'm already test sent notification using desktop to my iphone using AdHoc with production cert with token, i could receive the notification from iphone device.

whenever i install into linux server with same token and cert (done convert to .pem) i can't recieve notification

i do try on, easyapns and apns-php (invalid token). its does not work.

please help, the CA cert already in server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that your server process can read the .pem file (file permissions and location are OK)?  Does this linux server have outbound TCP port 2195 open (some hosting services don't allow this by default)?

Comment: You can try with executing: `telnet gateway.push.apple.com 2195`